# Avoiding multiple if..elseif statements

Tags: java, if-statement

I am in the process of writing an Android app that spends a great deal of time resolving Latitude/Longitude to [UTM coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system).  My current code for establishing the UTM Zone letter goes like this

```
if (Lat<-72) Letter='C';
else if (Lat<-64) Letter='D';
else if (Lat<-56) Letter='E';
else if (Lat<-48) Letter='F';
else if (Lat<-40) Letter='G';
else if (Lat<-32) Letter='H';
else if (Lat<-24) Letter='J';
else if (Lat<-16) Letter='K';
else if (Lat<-8) Letter='L';
else if (Lat<0) Letter='M';
else if (Lat<8) Letter='N';
else if (Lat<16) Letter='P';
else if (Lat<24) Letter='Q';
else if (Lat<32) Letter='R';
else if (Lat<40) Letter='S';
else if (Lat<48) Letter='T';
else if (Lat<56) Letter='U';
else if (Lat<64) Letter='V';
else if (Lat<72) Letter='W';
else Letter='X';
```

Whilst this works it appears to be a horribly inefficient way of dong things. Most of my users will be in Zone U which means as things stand the app is performing 16 failed `if..elseif` tests prior to establishing the right zone letter.

Easily set right by adjusting the order of the `if..elseifs`? True but I cannot but help thinking that there has got to be a cleaner way to do this.  I am still something of a Java newbie so although have experimented with HashMaps etc I have failed to make much headway.

Is a more elegant approach possible?

Comment: Don't worry about performance that unless you know this is a bottleneck, 16 else-ifs might be very cheap compared to other things that your application is doing. I would worry about readability and maintainability of your solution. @AndyTurner suggested an answer which addresses both, though.

Comment: unrelated: java naming convention suggests you write your variable names in lower camel case, with lower case first character. [More info on oracle website](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Comment: Your edit doesn't have the same behaviour as the original code. If `lat` is -75 it returns 'X' instead of 'C'. I don't know which you wanted but it's worth checking. I don't think the edit will ever return 'C'.

Comment: @Holloway - My corrected code deals with that issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
  char Letter = "CDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWX".charAt((int)((Lat + 80) / 8);
```

perhaps with some clamping to ensure that `Lat` is in a suitable range (an alternative being throwing an exception, since UTM is undefined outside this range):

```
  ClampedLat = Math.min(Math.max(Lat, -80), 84);
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the question author)*.

For the benefit of anyone else running into this question: Based on the answer @AndyTurner I ended up doing this:

```
public static char testIt(double lat)
{
 return "CCCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXXX".charAt((int)(Math.ceil((lat + 90)/ 8)));
}
```

An explanation is in order here:

- Adding 90 ensures that we are dealing with a nice 0-180 range that can be handled in a neater way - and probably better/faster than using `Math.min/max`
- Below -72 degrees the Zone letter is always C and above 72 degrees it is always X. Rather than deal with these issues by putting in an `if..` test we simply artifically extend the zone letter range at either end by padding it with extra Cs and Xs as required.

A handy graphical reference for checking the validity of the result is this [UTM grid chart](http://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm). I have coded my own test [here](https://ideone.com/X5YhyT).